# Java application in Linux that call .NET Mono with IKVM

Tags: java, c#, linux, mono, ikvm

I want to make simple example of java calling .net assembly created with mono on linux.

I have this very simple C# class called MyClass in ClassLibrary project called MonoLib

```
using System;

    namespace MonoLib
    {
        public class MyClass
        {        
            public static void TestDotNet()
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Hi I am from .Net");
            }
        }
    }
```

In order to use the class functionality I entered command

```
 ikvmstub Desktop/Mono/MonoLib/MonoLib/bin/Debug/MonoLib.dll
```

as it is explained on    http://mono-project.com/Java

which created MonoLib.jar

Then I want to test MonoLib.jar in pure java class called Demo.js

```
import cli.MonoLib.*;
public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyClass.TestDotNet();
        }
}
```

When I try to compile it with command:

```
javac -classpath MonoLib.jar Demo.java
```

I get this error:

```
Demo.java:4: cannot access cli.System.Object
class file for cli.System.Object not found
            MyClass.TestDotNet();
                   ^
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong ans is this correct approach.

**EDIT1:**

From answer below I concluded that problem is that my java application does not see mscorlib functionality thus it says "cli.System.Object not found"
That is why I need to extend this command

javac -classpath MonoLib.jar Demo.java

to add mscorlin.jar to classpath. **Can I add multiple jars with one command?**
Because I need mscorlib.jar added as well.

I have tried to add them in one folder called MonoTest and run this command

```
 javac -classpath /home/user/MonoTest/* Demo.java
```

The result was

javac: invalid flag: /home/user/MonoTest/mscorlib.jar
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options

**EDIT2**

Idealy I would like to have like bridge class that facades all .net functionality for java like:

```
import cli.MonoLib.*;
    public class Demo {
            public static void DotNetViaJava {
                MyClass.TestDotNet();
            }
    }



public class DemoTest {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Demo.DotNetViaJava();
        }
}
```

I need java class in this example Demo.java that once compiled with IKVM can be used with in any java app with out IKVM.

**EDIT3**

I have found out that all jars generated with ikvmstub can be used only on IKVM vistual machine on top of .net. This means that all my java code has to be executed in IKVM runtime? Is so, what are the limitation of that, should I change my platform for calling few methods form .net? It does not seem as interoperability to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need also to add mscorlib.jar to the classpath. This is a stub from the mscorlib.

Comment: I have created mscorlib.jar now how to add it? When I add it to CLASSPATH with  export CLASSPATH="/home/user/mscorlib.jar" it still reports the same error. Class path was empty line before.

Comment: Please have a look at my question, I would be satisfied if I could get answer on  "Can I add multiple jars with one command?"

Comment: @eomeroff You add it like any other jar file: javac -classpath mscorlib.jar:MonoLib.jar Demo.java

Comment: Thank you. One more think how to run it? ikvm -classpath .:MonoLib.jar Demo fails. NoClassFoundError I believe it still needs mscorlib.jar

Comment: @eomeroff javac and ikvm are different things. Open a new question to this new problem.